# is there a better way to write this mysql select query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.* 
FROM jobs 
INNER JOIN user_table 
ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid WHERE 
(user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND approved = 1) OR 
(user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND approved = 2)
```

the way i used to have it, which didn't work was:

```
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.* 
FROM jobs INNER JOIN user_table 
ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid WHERE 
user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND approved = 1 OR approved = 2
```

the first one works, but was wondering if there is a shorter way.  the second one is shorter but doesn't work because it pulls records that approved equals 2 but don't have user id equaling the session userid.

Comment: `AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND approved = 1 OR approved = 2
```

to

```
user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2)
```

in the 2nd query

Answer (score 2):

You can try the IN syntax:

```
WHERE user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." 
  AND approved IN (1,2)
```

If you create a compound index on `usertable(userid, approved)` this query will exploit that index (if `approved` is in `user_table`, which I can't tell from your question).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT jobs.*, user_table.* 
FROM jobs JOIN user_table 
ON jobs.userid = user_table.userid WHERE 
user_table.userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2)
```